# Is it possible in Quickbase to create a URL to an Add Record page which partially fills in fields on the form?

Tags: database, api

I have a Quickbase app with a form for adding records. On an intranet page, I have a link to the add record form. When a user clicks on that link, Quickbase opens the add record form. However, I would like to supply values for some of the fields on the form as parameters in the URL.

I am aware of API_AddRecord, but as I understand it, that can only be used for completely filling in all required fields and saving the record. The disprec parameter can be used to see the record, but doesn't keep the record in add mode without committing the record.

What I need to do, is to fill in a couple of the fields, but keep the record in add mode, allowing the user to fill in a couple more fields. The URLs on the intranet page are actually generated in a grid, so there are some fields that are already known then the user clicks on the link, and I don't want the user to have to type them in again.

Can this be done? Thanks for your input.

Answer (score 0):

Sure. Folks do this all the time. Use `a=API_GenAddRecordForm&_fid_1="foo"&_fid_2="bar"` where the number are the Field IDs of the fields you want to fill out, and "foo" and "bar" are the values you want to fill in.